# pnpm firebase app "Could not find a declaration file for module 'mime'"

Tags: typescript, express, google-cloud-functions, monorepo, pnpm

I'm trying to switch from yarn to pnpm in my turborepo monorepo.
When running lint or build I get this error:

```
../../node_modules/.pnpm/@types+serve-static@1.15.5/node_modules/@types/serve-static/index.d.ts:4:20 
- error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'mime'. 
'/path-to-project/node_modules/.pnpm/mime@3.0.0/node_modules/mime/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

It looks like some levels down my dependency graph @types/mime is installed but it is both deprecated and redundant, as stated on the npm page:
*This is a stub types definition. mime provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed*

- When using yarn I do not get this issue.
- When starting up another node/express project with pnpm I find the same dependencies in .pnpm but I do not get the issue.

Digging into *root/node_modules/.pnpm* and *root/pnpm-lock.yaml* the dependency leading to the issue seems to look like:

```
firebase-functions@4.8.2 --> @types/express@4.17.3 --> @types/serve-static@1.15.5 --> @types/mime@4.0.0
```

I have tried:

- pnpm store prune
- reinstall pnpm
- resinstall packages in *root/apps/project*
- Cleaned the entire project multiple times for any cache folders, node_modules and .lock files. Then reinstalled all dependencies.

Any ideas why I am getting this issue?

pnpm v8.15.5

*root/apps/project/tsconfig.json*

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017"
  },
  "compil
```

eOnSave": true,
"include": [
"src"
]
}

*root/apps/project/package.json*

```
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^12.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.8.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "event-dee-types": "workspace:*",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^3.1.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.0"
  },
```

*root/package.json*

```
 "dependencies": {
    "daisyui": "4.6.0",
    "dotenv-cli": "^7.2.1",
    "next": "latest",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.10.4",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.22",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.7",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-custom": "workspace:*",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "sass": "^1.62.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.1",
    "turbo": "latest",
    "typescript": "^5.0.4"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove by using the following command:

```
pnpm remove @types/mime
```